# injecting arabic text in div at runtime as ajax responce shows weired characters

Tags: arabic

I have a php page which supports arabic text properly.
I am using ajax to get some arabic text from server.php file but when i try to create dynamic div and put ajax responce (which is mixture of numbers and arabic text) in it...it doesnt work and shows me some unreadable dark squares like this ����� �� ��� ����

Whats the problem ? how to solve it ?
Thanks in advance

http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/op.png

Comment: is the encoding utf-8 for server.php ?

Comment: Yes server.php is saved using utf-8, i even tried printing arabic text directly on server.php page, it works. I will attach snapshot here...please take a look.

Comment: http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/op.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using mysql on that page? if so use:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $connection);

// Set the active MySQL database

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
```

Comment: I see from your example that you are fetching from the database. So you must set the code above in server.php

Comment: @AmitPatil so if you don't mind mark this question as answered by clicking the Vee icon next to the answer :)

Comment: Yeh i tried that but i have reputation score < 15 so i cant vote up :(  whoooa just found that i can mark it as accepted answer....DONE.